# setInterval and clearInterval not working with if()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do an AJAX refresh every 7 seconds on some data coming into an AJAX results `div`.

I need to control when it happens as I have lots of events like text editing and draggable stuff done through jQueryUI. I set up a function with a condition and an `if` statement to either set up an interval or clear it depending on the condition.

But my function seems to recognise a true state but not a false one. Any ideas or is their a better way to achieve what I want?  Many thanks for your time!

```
var intervalStart = true;

function setupAjaxInterval(condition){
    if (condition == true) {
        var refreshContent = setInterval(function() {
            var datastring = 'refreshpage=true&projid=' + proj_id + '&uid=' + uid;
            ajaxUploadData(datastring);
            alert('pagerefresh');
        }, 7000);
    }
    else if (condition == false) {
        clearInterval(refreshContent);
        alert('nofresh');
    }
}

setupAjaxInterval(intervalStart);
//works for true but not false.
```

Comment: `But my function seems to recognise a true state but not a false one.` Thats because `condition` is never being set to false.

Comment: i know that, when I set the variable to false its not recognising it.

Comment: Are you simply changing `intervalStart` to `false` and then re-running the script?  If so, `refreshContent` is undefined and you cannot `clearInterval(refreshContent)`.

Comment: `if(true) {...} else if(false) {...}` is the same as `if(true) {...} else {...}`.

Comment: Works fine in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/suQa2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with scope here.

You declare `var refreshCount` within the if statement so it doesn't exist in the else anymore.

```
var refreshContent;
function setupAjaxInterval(condition){
    if (condition == true) {
        refreshContent = setInterval(function() {
            var datastring = 'refreshpage=true&projid=' + proj_id + '&uid=' + uid;
            ajaxUploadData(datastring);
            alert('pagerefresh');
        }, 7000);

    }
    else if (condition == false) {
        clearInterval(refreshContent);
        alert('nofresh');
    }
}
```

Comment: `refreshContent` has to go outside the function, no?  JS is actually rather odd in terms of scope where blocks don't matter, but functions do.

Comment: No, `refreshContent` exists throughout the function, even if it is declared inside the `if` statement (due to hosting).

Comment: @Felix that's actually false. The refreshCount will go out of scope outside of the if statement and be inaccessible in the else. This only works trickling down scope, not upwards or sidewards.

Comment: @Felix perhaps... but doesn't exist next time you run the function

Comment: @Mala You're right, the variable would go out of scope after the function and get unset. Fixed it, even though this means that you pollute the global namespace which is always icky : (

Comment: @Mala: Yes, that's the problem, but not that it is declared inside the `if` statement. Just moving it outside the `if` does not help, it has to be made persistent between function calls. @Alexander: It's not possible to create an `if...if else` statement where both branches are executed, but maybe two `if` statements proof my point: http://jsfiddle.net/zJahQ/. JavaScript does not have block scope, only function scope.

Comment: @FelixKling You're right about the hoisting (Learned something :)) http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting But you still have the inter-function-call issue to deal with, hence you need a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you declare `refreshContent` inside the function. Once the function returns, you lose the reference, so when you then call it with false later, `refreshContent` is no longer defined.

To fix this, put `var refreshContent;` outside the function.

EDIT: either that or remove the `var` in front of it and make it global.

Comment: This is not a scope issue - `refreshContent` has scope throughout the function, therefore it is available throughout the `if` statement.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan It has scope only in the if statement, not throughout the function. Also the else won't get triggered in the same function call as the if so you need cross function call (global) scope.

Answer (score 0):

`refreshContent` is not defined you set it inside if

```
var refreshContent;
function setupAjaxInterval(condition){
```

Answer (score -1):

refreshContent is set as a local variable within the scope of the

```
 if( condidtion == true )
```

so when you enter the

```
 else if( condition == false )
```

refreshContent is no longer defined.

you need to make refreshContent defined ouside the scope of the function

Comment: As @FelixKling pointed out elsewhere, hoisting puts the var declaration at the beginning of the function, so if ... else scope is not a problem.

Comment: exists or not its undefined, http://jsfiddle.net/eEPWM/ and isnt the return of setInterval

Comment: Variables can exist but still have the value of `undefined`. Also you're not actually alerting the `refreshContent` when `condition == true;` Please see http://jsfiddle.net/eEPWM/1/

Comment: when the second call is made to stop the timer the value of refreshContent is not the correct value, thats there the error lies, not that it exists but is undefined.

Comment: Yes, but like I said in my first comment, that's not because `refreshContent` doesn't exist outside of the if because it does. That's because `refreshContent` stops existing after the function returns (So the next function call it's redeclared to `undefined`) By moving it to the global scope the variable will persist through both function calls.

Comment: I concede firebug confirms that refreshContent exists within the full functions scope. So yes my definition of the variables scope is incorrect, however its scope as we have agreed is the issue.